# mod-rewrite to remove a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL

http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/file.php

I want to redirect it to

http://www.example.com/demo/folder1/file.php

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^folder 
RewriteRule /demo/folder(.*)  /folder1/folder2/$1
```

Comment: Patience, dear user. Not many people have even seen this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule is backwards - it works the other way around.

You can try with the following:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/(.*)$ /demo/folder1/$1 [R,L]
```

Or perhaps you'd like to make `folder1` dynamic:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/folder2/(.*)$ /demo/$1/$2 [R,L]
```

If one of these works for you, and you would like to make the redirect permanent, you can change `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]`.

**Note:** You do not need to first two lines (`RewriteCond`), they are unnecessary.

Comment: I guess the first rule might be necessary if this is not under the `www.example.com` virtual host and multiple sites share this directory